# Can't use .aidl files across library projects?

Tags: android, aidl

In the spirit of re-using code, I'm trying to create a few library projects.  However, I seem to run into a problem defining .aidl files that span the libraries.  Here is the problem:

In library A I have Foo.java and Foo.aidl.  Foo.java is Parcelable so the aidl declaration is:

```
Foo.aidl:

package com.example.library.A;
parcelable Foo;
```

Now I'm trying to create library B.  In library B I want to define a service interface that uses class Foo:

```
IMyService.aidl:

package com.example.library.B;
import com.example.library.A.Foo;

interface IMyService {
    void requestSomething(in Foo fooBug);
}
```

This file does not compile complaining that it couldn't find the import for Foo.  I've tried referencing library A and I've tried adding the library project as an external jar, but neither work.

Is there a limitation that I don't know about?  Am I doing something wrong with my project setup??

I should probably mention that I've used library A directly in a project with no problem so I'm confident that lib A is not the problem.

Comment: This works fine for me - both using a library's AIDL classes in a non-library project, and in another library.  

Your Eclipse projects should have an item 'Library Projects' in their trees. Ensure that B's entry contains a reference to the expected JAR of A.

Comment: I recall it working for me with some prototypes I wrote a while back.  But it doesn't now.  I suspect updating to the v14 of the tools broke it: http://tools.android.com/recent/buildchangesinrevision14

Comment: I have it working, but I'm not happy with the solution.  In lib B, I had to add the com.example.library.A package and copy the Foo.aidl file into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have it working, but I'm not happy with the solution. In lib B, I had to add a com.example.library.A package and copy the Foo.aidl file into it.

Comment: Didn't this cause issues when running an app that uses lib B?

I'm getting `Duplicate class ... found in modules ... (lib A) and ... (lib B)` errors.